# Is there a Visual Studio 2010 Add On for Tabbed Multi-Monitor support

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, plugins, multiple-monitors, add-on

In Visual Studio 2010 you can drag tabs out to separate windows but you can not collect them together as additional tabbed elements.  Is there a VS 2010 add-on to allow you to group your extra windows into tabs?  It would be really nice to have a set of tabs on each of my monitors.

Comment: @ChrisDwyer: whilst not strictly code related, it is a valid question for StackOverflow as many of us use Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

The best place to look is the [Visual Studio Gallery for 2010 Extensions](http://bit.ly/cVYpeV). If you are lucky someone else has already had the idea and created an extension (VSIX) for you.

Otherwise, why do you have a go at writing it yourself by grabbing a copy of the [Visual Studio 2010 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=47305CF4-2BEA-43C0-91CD-1B853602DCC5&displaylang=en) and read the [Getting Started Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166439%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

**UPDATE:** I just stumbled on this awesome Visual Studio Extension that **may do want you are looking** for: [Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef).

Comment: No there is no such thing in the Visual Studio 2010 Pro Power Tools.

Comment: @khebbie: Whilst there is nothing *explicitly* in the Pro Power Tools extension - the Document Tab extension does allow you organise your code tabs and could be helpful to the OP and anyone else that finds this question. Note: the **may do what you are looking for** part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

Productivity Power Tools does it, and it's free. The feature is called Document Well.